# How to display a Date-Value from a DataReader in a TextBox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
 Date.Text = reader["dateintable"].ToShortDateString();
```

I want to get the date value from an sql table and display it in a textbox using executereader

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ToShortDateString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-5.0) if you have a `DateTime`. But you have just an `Object`. You need to cast it:

```
Date.Text = ((DateTime)reader["dateintable"]).ToShortDateString();
```

Another way is using [`GetDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), but you need the column-index first:

```
Date.Text = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("dateintable")).ToShortDateString();
```